# Using JWT in my angular 2 application and storing it in localStorage. However, how do I handle for when that item doesn't exist?

Tags: javascript, angular, jwt

I've created a `token-service.ts` that calls my back end auth API which returns a JWT.  I store this JWT in localstorage as shown here in my `getToken()`:

```
getToken() {
  this.http.post('myAuthEndpoint', { credentials })
  .subscribe((res) => {
    const token = res.headers.get('Authorization')
    localStorage.setItem('id_token', token);
  });
}
```

In my `app.component.ts`, I am calling the `getToken()` in my `ngOnInit` method.

However, here's what I have in my `app.component.html`:

```
<navigation-top></navigation-top>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

And this is where I have an issue - In my `NavigationTop` component, I am calling my `getNavigationTop()` from my `top-navigation.service.ts` to populate the links and stuff.  The API call I make in `getNavigationTop()` requires the auth token that I get in my `getToken()`, but its null on init.

How can I handle this case?  Right now it works when I reload the page after the first load, because then I can get the value from localStorage:

```
getNavigationTop(): Observable<any> {
  let headers = new Headers({ 'Authorization': localStorage.getItem('token') });
  let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
  let data = this.http
    .get('my url', options)
    .map((res: Response) => {
      return res.json().navTop;
    })
    .catch(this.handleError);
  return data;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Move those to a service and add it into your main module as a provider.

Then do this below. You can then inject the service into any component and call them at will.

```
@Injectable()
export class TokenService {
    getToken() {
      this.http.post('myAuthEndpoint', { credentials })
      .subscribe((res) => {
        const token = res.headers.get('Authorization')
        localStorage.setItem('id_token', token);
        this.getNavigationTop(token);
      });
    }


    getNavigationTop(token?): Observable<any> {
      let headers = new Headers({ 'Authorization': token ? token: localStorage.getItem('token') });
```

and then in  component:

```
import {TokenService} from '..../';

...



    @Component
export class NavigationTop {

    constructor(private tokenService: TokenService) {
      }

    ngOnInit() {

    this.tokenService.getToken();
    }
```

Now if you run getNavigationTop again later, it will check for token argument(optional) first but if none exist, try localstorage instead.

Comment: Thanks.  The only issue here is that I have about a dozen services which are going to be using the `id_token`.  How would I handle in that case?  So the `<router-outlet>` would render some other component if I had hit `mysite.com/recent`, and that `RecentComponent` would fire off a HTTP request to `myapi.com/getRecentPhotos` which requires the `id_token`.  In such a case, how can I modify this code?  Sorry I've been struggling with this for a while, so I'm wondering if there's a better way.

Comment: Run get token onInit in the parent component that loads firsts.....since every services gets it from localStorage, I'm not seeing the issue.

Comment: Yes, but my `app.component` is rendering both `router-outlet` (which might render some component like RecentComponent, and also `<navigation-top></navigation-top>`.  NavigationTop is a header, and it is updated with some links from my API.  However, in my `app.component.ts` onInit, I'm calling getToken(), but at the same time my NavigationTop's onInit is calling getNavigationTop().  However, that call will not have the id_token since the getToken() hasn't finished yet.